# Why memory usage is so LOW on CentOS 7?

Tags: mysql, memory-management, centos, vps

MySQL memory usage on my 1GB centos 7 VPS was too high, and I ran this script: mysqltuner.com
Now usage is too low, about 30M (at all). This is not normal, can anybody tell me what exactly happened? Can't figure it out.

Comment: You ran a script that changed MySQL config obviously. Now your MySQL is slow as snail. What kind of answer are you after? Don't change config if you don't understand what it does.

Comment: I understand that. I asked about this: why 30M at all? Is CentOS memory usage really so low?

Comment: 30M because your mysql config says so.

Answer (score -1):

Generlly installation of MySQL on a VPS consumes little RAM. I guess you have installed some applicatons on your server, for example, a web-based control panel, which eats up a steep amount of and results into a run out of ram.

If that is the case, try to uninstall the app and find an alternative that base on desktop. I will suggest you to give [VPSrobots](https://vpsrobots.com/) a try.